# Dont Allow to update attributes in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel when adding an attribute to `$fillable` then we can mass assignment in both Create/Update but I want to allow an attribute to mass assignment in create but not allow for update. Now I use Updating Event to achieve this. Is there a better way?

```
protected static function boot()
{
    static::updating(function ($product) {
        $product->price = $product->getOriginal('price');
    }
}
```

Comment: I would stick to the code you currently have, since its in the same file as the model.

Comment: I would dynamically change the `$fillable` array depending on the action

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the `Obeserver`. Because it gives you much more flexibility.

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\User;

class UserObserver
{

    /**
     * Listen to the User updating event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updating(User $user)
    {
      if($user->isDirty(['price'])){
        // it is updated return false.
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `price` attribute from `$fillable` and use `forceCreate()` to create a record:

```php
$product = Product::forceCreate([
    // ...
    'price' => 10.50,
];
```

This will allow you to set value on create, but when you update model via `$product->fill()` price will not change because it is not fillable. You can always change value of price directly omitting the mass assignment:

```php
$product->price = 11.50;
$product->save();
```